# How to check if model has even number of relationed records?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have User model with `hasMany` relationship  and I need to write a query and get only those users which has even number of relationed records.

Is it possible to somehow use `whereHas` with %2 condition?
Or how else to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) alongside havingRaw to do this:

```
  $usersWithEvenRelatedModel= User::withCount('relatedModels as relatedCount')
  ->havingRaw('relatedCount %2 = 0')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some grouping/having and raw queries:

```
$userWithEvenRelations = User::whereHas('related', function ($q) {
   $q->groupBy('user_id')->havingRaw('MOD(COUNT(user_id), 2) = 0');
});
```